# org-mode export define derived backend

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I want to defined a new export backend derived from org-html-export backend in order to remove the divs that appear in the code (something like slimhtml but a little less drastic) and maybe later I want to change the styling a bit with some other html, my first attempt is just to remove divs.

My attempt was to do this

```
(defun my-org-html-section (section contents info)
  "Transcode a SECTION element from Org to HTML.
CONTENTS holds the contents of the section.  INFO is a plist
holding contextual information."
  (let ((parent (org-export-get-parent-headline section)))
    ;; Before first headline: no container, just return CONTENTS.
    (if (not parent) contents
      ;; Get div's class and id references.
      (let* ((class-num (+ (org-export-get-relative-level parent info)
               (1- (plist-get info :html-toplevel-hlevel))))
         (section-number
          (and (org-export-numbered-headline-p parent info)
           (mapconcat
            #'number-to-string
            (org-export-get-headline-number parent info) "-"))))
        ;; Build return value.
    (format "%s"
        (or contents ""))))))

;;;###autoload
(defun my-org-html-export-to-html
  (&optional async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist)
  "Export current buffer to a HTML file.
If narrowing is active in the current buffer, only export its
narrowed part.
Return output file's name."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((extension (concat "." (or (plist-get ext-plist :html-extension)
                    org-html-extension
                    "html")))
     (file (org-export-output-file-name extension subtreep))
     (org-export-coding-system org-html-coding-system))
    (org-export-to-file 'html file
      async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist)))
      


(org-export-define-derived-backend 'my-html 'html
  :translate-alist '((section . my-org-html-section))
  :menu-entry '(?s "Export to html"
      ((?H "As html buffer" my-org-html-export-to-html))))
```

which is an alteration of [org-mode-export](https://github.com/yyr/org-mode/blob/d8494b5668ad4d4e68e83228ae8451eaa01d2220/lisp/ox-html.el#L3141)

But when I export I still get the divs.
Any idea why my custom export does not use the custom section ?
I am still new to elisp.

Comment: Have you defined `my-org-html-export-to-html`?

Comment: Sorry yes, it is a remnant of some of my attempts. It was a copy/paste of org-html-export-to-html. Maybe the problem is here, I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question as indicated by JeanPierre the error was in `my-org-html-export-to-html`, I must replace `'html` by `'my-html` in `org-export-to-file`.

This solved my issue.

Comment: Still, you create a menu entry for exporting to buffer but it exports to file.

Comment: Yes you are right, a typo, in fact now I copied/pasted the rest and I can export either buffer or file. So it is corrected.